# An array that can deal with up to N elements in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

At the moment I have an array constructed like this:

```
Car[] garage = new Car[5];
garage[0] = new Car("Ford", "Focus", "S301 ABN");
garage[1] = new Car("Opel", "Astra", "WA55 AAP");
garage[2] = new Car("Ford", "Explorer", "L66 4ABE");
garage[3] = new Car("Dodge", "Viper", "FA55 SAM");
garage[4] = new Car("Ferrari", "F50", "SAS3 47S");
```

However, I need the size of the array to be set by a user defined value which comes from a JComboBox. I've got the JComboBox setting the value working but it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because elements exist that aren't within the array index bounds. So my question is, what way should I go about adding the elements to the array after the user selects the size of the array?

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Please post some code relating to what *doesn't work*, rather than what does :)

Comment: ArrayList<Car> would solve this Exception, but if you have constructed an array of the correct size, this exception shouldn't be thrown.

Comment: The problem is the user can pick an array of size between 2 and 10. Therefore, I need to have 10 objects already made and a way to add only the required amount to the array.

Comment: `Car[] garage = new Car[10];` // correct size. Then check bounds and if there is anything in that part of the garage (`null` means there is no car). Or keep a count. Although an `ArrayList` -- *as already noted twice* -- would handle this much better and simpler :-)

Comment: Is this homework? If so, tag it as such (that will direct answers to "use an array" even if this is not normally advisable).

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I used an ArrayList as suggested and it is now functioning as it should. Also added the tag as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import `java.util.ArrayList`, and use the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) data structure instead of a normal array.

To do the same thing your code you posted, you'd use code like something like this:

```
List<Car> garage = new ArrayList();
garage.add(new Car("Ford", "Focus", "S301 ABN"));
//etc
```

To get the nth element of the garage, use `garage.get(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the nth element. Using this I made an ArrayList of all the Car objects, then used a for loop to add them to the normal array like this:
                `List<Car> garage = new ArrayList();
                garage.add(new Car("Ford", "Focus", "S301 ABN"));
                garage.add(new Car("Opel", "Astra", "WA55 AAP"));
                garage.add(new Car("Ford", "Explorer", "L66 4ABE"));
                
                Car[] cars = new Car[sNum];
                for(int j = 0; j < sNum; j++){
                    cars[j] = garage.get(j);
                }`

Comment: You could do that.  an array list can be used in place of an array entirely, though...